# Kubernetes destroying microservices with a DB

Tags: java, docker, container, web-services, clustering

How can Kubernetes recover the data of my microservices when it has to be removed due a healthcheck failure? How will the new instance have the same information on the DB?

Answer (score 0):

You can create PersistentVolumes that a Pod can use but you have to save the state of your application by your self as you have to expect that data in memory will be lost.